# What is a primary decomposition of the ideal $I = \langle xy, x - yz \rangle$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Given the ring $k[x,y,z]$, where $k$ is a field, and an ideal $I=(xy,x-yz)$, find a primary decomposition of $I$.

I tried to draw the graph of the variety of $I$ and get a decomposition of $(x,y)\cap(x,z)$ (the two prime ideals corresponds to the irreducible components of the variety), but apparently these two ideals are not the primary decomposition of $I$, and I don't know how to fix this.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me. thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only use geometry to find the primary decomposition if the given ideal is actually an intersection of prime ideals.  In your case, it is true that
$$
V(xy,x-yz) \;=\; V(x,y) \cup V(x,z)
$$
but
$$
(xy,x-yz) \;\subsetneq\; (x,y) \cap (x,z).
$$
For example, $x\in (x,y)\cap (x,z)$, but $x\notin (xy,x-yz)$.

Instead, the given ideal is the intersection of two primary ideals
$$
(xy,x-yz) \;=\; Q_1 \cap Q_2
$$
where the ***radicals*** of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are the prime ideals that you have found:
$$
\sqrt{Q_1}=(x,y) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sqrt{Q_2} = (x,z).
$$
To find $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, observe that
$$
(xy,x-yz) \;=\; (y^2z,x-yz),
$$
since $xy - y^2 z = y(x-yz)$.  We can now factor the $y^2z$:
$$
(y^2z,x-yz) \;=\; (y^2,x-yz) \cap (z,x-yz)
$$
To prove this equation, observe that all three ideals contain $(x-yz)$.  The quotient $k[x,y,z]/(x-yz)$ is isomorphic to $k[y,z]$, and obviously $(y^2z)=(y^2)\cap (z)$ in $k[y,z]$, so lifting back to $k[x,y,z]$ gives the desired equation.

It is easy to see that $(y^2,x-yz)$ is primary, and $(z,x-yz) = (x,z)$ is actually prime.  We conclude that
$$
Q_1 = (y^2,x-yz) \qquad\text{and}\qquad Q_2 = (x,z)
$$

Comment: Hi Jim. I am intrigued by your sentence "You can only use geometry to find the primary decomposition if the given ideal is actually an intersection of prime ideals.". Is there no way to find the primary decomposition by "infinitesimal" arguments, looking at multiplicities and stuff ? I don't know the answer, but I was hoping for a Yes! Thanks.

Comment: @redfiloux  I think this is what [schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28mathematics%29) are for, but I don't know much about those.

Comment: Okay no problem, thanks :D !

Comment: Dear Jim, I know a bit of scheme theory and yet I couldn't have solved this problem. So: congratulations (+1) and don't worry about "not knowing much about schemes"!

Comment: @JimBelk You wrote "Instead, the given ideal is the intersection of two primary ideals", but how do we know this from the information beforehand?

Comment: @JimBelk Also, how do we know $(y^2z,x-yz) = (y^2,x-yz) \cap (z,x-yz)$ from the fact that $x-yz$ is contained in all three ideals?

Comment: @user46372819 The statement "Instead, the given ideal is the intersection..." is what the rest of the answer proves.  We don't know it beforehand.  The fact that $(y^2 z, x-yz) = (y^2,x-yz)\cap (z,x-yz)$ comes from the fact that all three ideals contain $(x-yz)$ *and* $\pi((y^2 z,x-yz)) = \pi((y^2,x-yz))\cap \pi((z,x-yz))$, where $\pi\colon k[x,y,z] \to k[x,y,z]/(x-yz)$ is the quotient homomorphism.

Comment: @JimBelk Nice. Does it follow that we can always split up an ideal in that way? For example, for any $f \in k[x,y]$, is it true that $(x^n y^m,f)=(x^n,f) \cap (y^m,f)$?

Answer (score 5):

If you are planning to work more on ring theory, I recommend installing [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) on your computer. It is a computer algebra software for computing with rings and ideals and modules.

For example, to compute the primary decomposition of your ideal, one would type the following commands:

```
R = QQ[x,y,z]
I = ideal (x*y, x-y*z)
primaryDecomposition I

{ideal (z, x), ideal (y*z - x, y^2 , x*y)}
```

This actually disagrees with Jim Belk's answer above.

Comment: This doesn't disagree with Belk's idea because there may be different primary decompositions for an ideal, this answer is the same if we send $x$ to $yz$ in a homomorphism $\varphi: k[x,y,z]\mapsto k[y,z]$

Comment: Actually, I think this is the same answer that I have above.  Macaulay2 is automatically computing a Gröbner basis for the ideal $(y^2,x-yz)$, which is why the $xy$ appears.  The $xy$ is not necessary to generate the ideal, since $xy = y(x-yz) + z(y^2)$.

Comment: Macaulay2: +1, Jim Belk:+2